# Python pandas: convert dictionary to DataFrame with keys as row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert the following dictionary to dataframe:

```
x = {'a': {'list1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
           'list2': [5, 6, 7, 8]
          },
     'b': {'list1': [6, 7, 8, 9], 
           'list2': [4, 4, 3, 4]
          },
     'c': {'list1': [6, 45, 234, 4], 
           'list2': [213, 87, 243, 4]
          }
    }
```

the output dataframe should look like this:

```
letter   list1             list2
a        [1, 2, 3, 4]      [5, 6, 7, 8]
b        [6, 7, 8, 9]      [4, 4, 3, 4]
c        [6, 45, 234, 4]   [213, 87, 243, 4]
```

I have tried these methods:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(x)
                  a             b                  c
list1  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [6, 7, 8, 9]    [6, 45, 234, 4]
list2  [5, 6, 7, 8]  [4, 4, 3, 4]  [213, 87, 243, 4]
```

Secondly, I tried:

```
pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in x.items()}).reset_index()

  level_0 level_1                  0
0       a   list1       [1, 2, 3, 4]
1       a   list2       [5, 6, 7, 8]
2       b   list1       [6, 7, 8, 9]
3       b   list2       [4, 4, 3, 4]
4       c   list1    [6, 45, 234, 4]
5       c   list2  [213, 87, 243, 4]
```

The second way is close but then each "letter" have 2 rows. How do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) with rename index name and convert index by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to column `letter` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x).T.rename_axis('letter').reset_index()
print (df)
  letter            list1              list2
0      a     [1, 2, 3, 4]       [5, 6, 7, 8]
1      b     [6, 7, 8, 9]       [4, 4, 3, 4]
2      c  [6, 45, 234, 4]  [213, 87, 243, 4]
```

Or solution with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index').rename_axis('letter').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `orient` argument, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) -

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index').rename_axis('letter').reset_index()

  letter            list1              list2
0      a     [1, 2, 3, 4]       [5, 6, 7, 8]
1      b     [6, 7, 8, 9]       [4, 4, 3, 4]
2      c  [6, 45, 234, 4]  [213, 87, 243, 4]
```